# Python 2.7 still accessing Python 3.4 directories

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I installed Python 2.7 when I had already installed Python 3.4 on my system.

Now when I try to run python27 it still tries to access the Python 3.4 folders and thus getting errors.

```
C:\Users\user>python27
  File "E:\Python\Lib\site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It should access `E:\Python27` (which contains 2.7) instead of `E:\Python` (which contains 3.4).

The version and commands work:

```
C:\Users\Lorenz>python --version
Python 3.4.3

C:\Users\Lorenz>python27 --version
Python 2.7.9
```

I have both versions of Python in the environment variables.

EDIT: I just deleted all related 3.4 environment variables, and weirdly now, both 2.7 and 3.4 work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need environment variables (e.g. `PYTHONPATH`) for both installations, it'll be working for you. However I strongly suggest using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), it helps with isolating problems related to libraries AND installed interpreters.

Also nice [guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is nothing but trouble. There are better ways to add directories to `sys.path`, such as `.pth` files, but virtual environments are even better.

Comment: I had this exact issue.  `virtualenv -p c:\python27\python.exe` would also fail.  Removing all PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH vars solved this for me also.  I was able to re-add one PYTHONPATH variable pointing to python 3 with no problems.